# How do I assign a variable to an object name?

Tags: python

Tried the following, where "objectname" contains a string name, to be assigned on creation of an object.

```
for record in result:
    objectname = 'Customer' + str(record[0])
    print objectname
    customername = str(record[1])
    objectname = Customer(customername)
```

Where Customer is a class.

In my test, this loop runs twice printing "objectname" as Customer1 and Customer2, yet creates 2 objects, but the objects are called "objectname" (it overwrites each loop), opposed to the 2 unique objects Customer1 or Customer2.

Its simply not assigning strings(customer1,2) inside the variable, but purely the variables name.

I've tried assigning strings to the object name, but that gives a syntax error

Surely this must be done all the time, thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It has been *tried* all the time, but it isn't needed. In fact, it's a pretty awful way of doing it. Just use a collection.

Comment: Please correct the indentation in your example code. It is significant in Python, you know.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses and for being kind regarding my newbie knowledge of Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using a new variable for each customer you could store your object in a Python dictionary:

```
d = dict()

for record in result:
    objectname = 'Customer' + str(record[0])
    customername = str(record[1])
    d[objectname] = Customer(customername)

print d
```

## An example of objects stored in dictionaries

I just could'nt help my self writting some code (more than I set out to do). It's like addictive. Anyway, I would'nt use objects for this kind of work. I probably would use a sqlite database (could be saved in memory if you want). But this piece of code show you (hopefully) how you can use dictionaries to save objects with customer data in:

```
# Initiate customer dictionary
customers = dict()

class Customer:
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.address = None
        self.zip = None
        self.state = None
        self.city = None
        self.phone = None

    def add_address(self, address, zp, state, city):
        self.address = address
        self.zip = zp
        self.state = state
        self.city = city

    def add_phone(self, number):
        self.phone = number


# Observe that these functions are not belonging to the class.    
def _print_layout(object):
        print object.fname, object.lname
        print '==========================='
        print 'ADDRESS:'
        print object.address
        print object.zip
        print object.state
        print object.city
        print '\nPHONE:'
        print object.phone
        print '\n'

def print_customer(customer_name):
    _print_layout(customers[customer_name])

def print_customers():
    for customer_name in customers.iterkeys():
        _print_layout(customers[customer_name])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Add some customers to dictionary:
    customers['Steve'] = Customer('Steve', 'Jobs')
    customers['Niclas'] = Customer('Niclas', 'Nilsson')
    # Add some more data
    customers['Niclas'].add_address('Some road', '12312', 'WeDon\'tHaveStates', 'Hultsfred')
    customers['Steve'].add_phone('123-543 234')

    # Search one customer and print him
    print 'Here are one customer searched:'
    print 'ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo'
    print_customer('Niclas')

    # Print all the customers nicely
    print '\n\nHere are all customers'
    print 'oooooooooooooooooooooo'
    print_customers()
```

Comment: Well, Rotem, that used the same solution as me had a better name for the dictionary - "customers". Otherwise they are pretty much the same :)

Comment: sorry, started writing it while you were writing yours, it obviously is the same answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response and your time, I can see you're creating a dictionary, but it looks like your assigning the object to the dictionary, opposed to putting a value into the dictionary and then assining that to the object.

This is obviously the correct way to do this, but it seems counter-intuitive to me.. :S

Comment: Well, say that you have a customer named Steve, if you want to retrieve the Customer object for him (that may contain adress, phone numner etc), then you write d['Steve'] and that returns the object. It seems pretty intuitive to me :)

Comment: I see what you mean now, I've only just started with objects, so I have been literally making a class and assinging a name to an object using Steve = Customer(), then just returning by typing Steve.

Comment: Sorry, had to go out. Now I'm back. Your description is not completly true. You create a object from a class, that's right. But instead of assigning a name to your object (as you do a lot of times) you store your object in a dictionary. Because objects can be stored in diffrent ways. You can also store them in a list, but that way you will lose your way to easily look them up. You have to implement some way to search for the right object. Hope it make sence, otherwise ask again. If you don't understand dictionaries, look them up in 5.5 on http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html :)

Comment: To make it more clear (maybe) - When you store your object in the dictionary, you assign a keyword (think of a papper dictionary). In my sample above that keyword would be Steve

Comment: In my new sample there is one more thing I would probably change in a real case scenario (if I would use objects for this kind of data). That is that the print_customer-function should be a method in the class instead...

Answer (score 6):

It is generally not that useful to have dynamically generated variable names.  I would definitely suggest something like Niclas' answer instead, but if you know this is what you want here is how you can do it:

```
for record in result:
    objectname = 'Customer' + str(record[0])
    print objectname
    customername = str(record[1])
    exec '%s = Customer(%r)' % (customername, customername)
```

This will result in the variables `Customer1` and `Customer2` being added to the innermost scope, exactly like if you had executed the following lines:

```
Customer1 = Customer('Customer1')
Customer2 = Customer('Customer2')
```

When doing it this way you need to make sure that `customername` is a [valid Python identifier](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers).

Comment: This helps me understand the general idea better!

Comment: This is only answer that answers original question. Dictionary answer is not wrong, but also does not address original question.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a dictionary:

```
customers = {}
for record in result:
    objectname = 'Customer' + str(record[0])
    customers[customername] = Customer(str(record[1]))  #assignment to dictionary
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and your time, I can see you're creating a dictionary, but it looks like your assigning the object to the dictionary, opposed to putting a value into the dictionary and then assining that to the object. This is obviously the correct way to do this, but it seems counter-intuitive to me.. :S

Comment: I can't imagine in what way it seems more complicated or counter-intuitive, but to each his own I guess..